# Retrieve User information inside a filter

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Is it possible to retrieve User information inside a filter in symfony 1.4?

I know that in an action I can call

```
$this->getUser()
```

and in a template I use

```
$sf_user
```

but how can I do in a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Good practice:**

in action:

```
 $this->formFilter= new YourFormFilter(array(), array('user' => $this->getUser()));
```

and in your form filter class:

```
class YourFormFilter extends BaseYourFormFilter{

 public function configure(){

    $user = $this->getOption('user')
  }
}
```

**Bad practice:**

in your form filter class:

```
class YourFormFilter extends BaseYourFormFilter{

  public function configure(){

    $user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, but...what should I do if don't create manually the filter? It's called automatically by symfony lifecycle...I mean that I'm supposed to use the bad practice

Comment: @ilSavo Check my answer to see how to do it with using the admin generator.

Comment: I'm not in admin generator, but in front. In any case I solved with the solution above

Answer (score 2):

You should add a user option to the filter and pass the user object through that.

In a filter class:

```
public function configure()
{
  $this->user = $this->getOption('user');

  if (!$this->user instanceof sfBasicSecurityUser)
  {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('A user object is required as "user" option in ' . __METHOD__);
  }

  //...
}
```

In an action:

```
$this->filter = new YourFilter(array(), array('user' => $this->getUser()));
```

If you are using **admin generator** you can pass the user with overriding the `getFilterFormOptions` method of the generator configuration class.

```
class yourGeneratorConfiguration extends BaseYourGeneratorConfiguration
{
  /**
   * @return sfBasicSecurityUser
   */
  public function getUser()
  {
    return sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();
  }

  public function getFilterFormOptions()
  {
    return array('user' => $this->getUser());
  }

  // ...
}
```